# Who was that woman in Atlantis protecting one of Mother Boxes?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In *Justice League* (2017) movie, when Steppenwolf arrived in Atlantis to take one of Mother Boxes, a woman fought with him. She was capable of controlling water waves and she even trapped Steppenwolf in a bubble of water waves.

Who was she? And, what are her superpowers? Anything even from the comics?

Comment: It has been a bit, so I could be wrong, but I think it was Mera, played by Amber Heard...

Comment: https://www.inverse.com/article/13050-who-is-mera-the-character-amber-heard-will-play-in-justice-league

Comment: Do you think you should split this up since you asked three questions here?

Comment: @Odin1806 Fine. You won. :)

Comment: No hard feelings!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Mera](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0974015/characters/nm1720028?ref_=tt_cl_t13)

[image: Mera]

She appears to be a Queen of the sea, similar to Aquaman. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mera_(comics)) lists her powers as:

> Mera has the unique ability to form "hard water" objects, as well as super strength and powers related to her adaptation to live under water. She has been shown to be powerful enough to control, albeit briefly, huge amounts of water, enough to pull an entire army out to sea. Due to her intended role as an infiltrator and a killer, Mera received extensive training in Xebel, becoming a formidable opponent on her own.

Comment: In the comics at least, she's Aquaman's wife.

Comment: @RDFozz I read that too but didn't add it in explicitly because I don't know if the same is true for the film's universe.